# An inequality about the volume of convex body

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

For a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we denote by $\lambda S$ the dilation for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$\lambda S=\{\lambda x| x\in S\}.$$

Let $\Omega$ be a convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $0$ as barycenter. Put
$$a(t)=\frac{vol(t\Omega \bigcap -(2-t)\Omega)}{vol(\Omega)}(0\leq t\leq 1).$$
Then we want to know whether the following holds: $$\int_0^1 a(t)dt \geq \frac{n!2^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}.$$

I don't know the answer even for $n=2$. When $\Omega$ is a triangle,

\begin{equation}
    a(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
   t^2 & 0\leq t \leq \frac{2}{3}  \\
   -2t^2+4t-\frac{4}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \leq t\leq 1 \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
So $$\int_0^1a(t)dt=\frac{8}{27}.$$
It's known that $a(1)\geq \frac{2}{3}$ for convex polygon when $n=2$.